# Bad fit questions?

Tags: discussion

If I have a question that I know is a bad fit (off-topic) for SO, but I'm not sure where to ask it.
Should I ask it anyway, including a statement like follows?

> I know this is a bad question for SO, but I'm not sure where else to ask it.

Comment: No, you should not ask it anyway. If it is a bad question for SO, it'll be downvoted and / or closed as off topic, and if you do that too often, your account will be banned from posting more questions.

Comment: Put differently: do not knowingly waste everyone's time, our community doesn't react well to that.

Comment: Ok, that answers my question, thanks. I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting downvoted though.

Comment: Voting on Meta often signals 'agreement'. People are disagreeing you should post bad questions, even with a disclaimer.

Comment: Ok, I haven't used meta before, so I thought they thought it was a bad question, thanks again!

Comment: It is good that you asked first. Not many new users do that.

Comment: @BadProgrammer99 _"I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting downvoted though. "_ Relax, that's normal here.

Comment: People use the upvote button here to show agreement or to say "yes".  The answer to your question is NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! and that's why your question stands currently as -8. No damage to your SO rep.

Comment: If you're looking for site recommendations, see [meta.se].

Comment: Even the meta question is only wasting people's time.  When asking, "Is it okay to ask a question that I know I shouldn't ask?" the answer is self-evident.  You aren't learning anything you didn't know before asking the question (because the answer is in the question itself), you're just wasting the time of users on Meta instead of on main.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Of course not. That'd be wasting everyone's time.

Our community's time is wasted, as now they'll have to clean up your question. It wasn't suitable for SO in the first place, so it'll be closed as off-topic, and in all likelyhood downvoted. Our community could have been busy helping with more worthy questions.

It is also a waste of your time. You'll not likely get an answer. Instead, you'll have to deal with the downvotes, the comments asking why you posted the question, and the possibility of your account being placed under a question ban.

A disclaimer that you know it is a bad question won't stop this from happening. If anything, it'll make community members upset with you; it is one thing posting a bad question because you didn't learn enough about how the site works, it is quite another to know it is a bad question, and posting it *anyway*.

Don't do it. Don't waste time.